# How to prove that a rotation invariant gradient must be in the direction of the radius

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, symmetry

Let $f(x,y)$ be a smooth function on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Suppose that its gradient vector field
$$
\nabla f:=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)
$$
is invariant under rotations about the origin of $\mathbb{R}^2$. (Notice that we do not assume a priori that $f$ is invariant under rotations.)

> > Under this assumption, how to prove that $\nabla f$ is proportional to the radius vector $(x,y)$?

Comment: What do you mean by invariant? $Df(Qx) = Q Df(x)$ for orthogonal $Q$?

Comment: Actually I mean the induced vector field under any rotation is the same as the original vector field. But in our case I think it is the same as your definition except that $Q$ cannot contain a reflection.